# Google App Engine : Error Response: [14] Cloud Container build either failed or interrupted

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Been trying for some decent time to deploy a streamlit app on GAE - Google App Engine.
The cmd used is gcloud app deploy --version=thisName:

gcloud app deploy --version=gazelle --verbosity=debug

The last console outputs giving a final trace in the gcloud sdk code is :

```
Step #3 - "post-buildpack": Image eu.gcr.io/centered-snow-338721/appengine/default.gazelle:6e5e7a55XXXXXXXXXXXXXa329 copied to eu.gcr.io/centered-snow-338721/appe
ngine/default.gazelle:latest
Finished Step #3 - "post-buildpack"
PUSH
DONE
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /staging.centered-snow-338721.appspot.com/log-781821b2-cf98-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8945ceb.txt HTTP/1.1" 416 169
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG: Operation [apps/centered-snow-338721/operations/6e5e7a55-XXXXXXXXXXb51a329] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/centered-snow-338721/operations/6e5e7a55-XXXXXXXXXX6e5ab51a329] complete. Result:
{
    "done": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "Cloud Container build either failed or interrupted."
    },
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "createVersionMetadata": {
            "cloudBuildId": "781821b2-cfXXXXXXXXXXXXXf9c38945ceb"
        },
        "endTime": "2023-04-16T22:17:20.008Z",
        "insertTime": "2023-04-16T22:02:12.483Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
        "target": "apps/centered-snow-338721/services/default/versions/gazelle",
        "user": "whateveryoufly@gmail.com"
    },
    "name": "apps/centered-snow-338721/operations/6e5e7a55-10XXXXXXXXXXX5ab51a329"
}
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [14] Cloud Container build either failed or interrupted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 127, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 692, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 471, in Deploy
    self.api_client.DeployService(new_version.service, new_version.id,
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\appengine_api_client.py", line 230, in DeployService
    return operations_util.WaitForOperation(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 307, in WaitForOperation
    completed_operation = waiter.WaitFor(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 261, in WaitFor
    operation = PollUntilDone(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 322, in PollUntilDone
    operation = retryer.RetryOnResult(
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 249, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "C:\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone
    raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [14] Cloud Container build either failed or interrupted.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [14] Cloud Container build either failed or interrupted.type here
```

I tried so many changes to the app.yaml file... tweaking readiness/liveliness checks, auto/manual scaling..

I would expect, first the INSTANCE to start (which strangely occured once with 3 instances, but seemed to crash quite quick thereafter, but can't even reach this step anymore today), being able to to see the instance in the gougle cloud AppEngine/Instance pane.

I notice that ErrNO [14] is not edited in any forum afaik..

Thanks for help!

Comment: Include the contents of your ```app.yaml``` file